# Cannot Add items to custom painted JPanel

Tags: java, swing

When I try to use `myCustomPanel.add(someComponent)` it does not add...

Here is my custom JPanel class:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


/**
 *
 * @author Jacob
 */
public class OSXMainPanel extends JPanel {
    public static final long serialVersionUID = 24362462L;


    private Image image;


    public OSXMainPanel() {
        super.setOpaque(true);
        try {
            image = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(new java.net.URL(getClass().getResource("/assets/background.png"), "background.png"));
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }


    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if (isOpaque())
        {
            g.setColor(getBackground());
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
        for(int w = 0; w < this.getWidth(); w = w + 50) {
            for(int h = 0; h < this.getHeight(); h = h + 50) {
                g.drawImage(image, w, h, 50, 50, this);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Post your SSCCE (http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem. There is nothing in the code you posted that would prevent the child components from being painted. If you see the image then you should see the components. So the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this isn't working is because your paintComponent method isn't painting the added components. Calling super.paintComponent(g) at the start of the paintComponent method should fix this.

Comment: +1 And in doing that, the fillRect() for the background color becomes unnecessary.

Comment: paintComponent does not draw child components. You must be thinking of paintComponents.

Comment: -1, I agree with Russ. Take a look at the section from the Swing tutorial on Painting which explains this in more detail: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html

Comment: Based on the link posted by camickr, overriding paintComponent instead of overriding paint directly allowed the paintChildren call to draw normally, and solved my problem.  The original example should be drawing child components.

Answer (score 0):

It should not be necessary to call super.paintComponent(Graphics g) to paint child components. The call is useful, to draw the background, but not strictly necessary.

I tested the code on Java 6 and it worked fine for me. The only modification I made was to add the following line in the constructor:

```
add(new JLabel("Test"));
```

I do not have the background image file so the image drawing code was doing nothing. Either the background image is somehow obscuring the child components or there is a bug in the code that adds a child component. Try commenting out the drawImage call and see if child components become visible.

Answer (score -2):

I would call updateUI()

```
myPanel.add(new JLabel("wanna see it"));
// change of look and feel
myPanel.updateUI();
```

after adding the component - if you want to update whole look and feel. Otherwise use revalidate().

```
myPanel.add(new JLabel("wanna see this"));
myPanel.revalidate();
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but the problem is that it isn't being painted at all. The code that normally paints what has been added to the panel is being overridden and isn't painting the added components. Calling updateUI or revalidate wont solve this.